# Default Axis Format of PosixCt

Tags: r, posixct

Is there a way I can change the default format for how POSIXct labels appear when using `plot` and when they are part of a dataframe (`Date HH:MM` instead of just `HH:MM`)?

I would be nice if I could do this without having to issue an `axis` command each time or converting the dataframe to an `xts` object.

Comment: The following is no very clean (it issues a lot of warnings), but works: `plot(d, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`. You could also try to redefine `graphics::axis.POSIXct` (which is tricky, because it is in a package) or use `ggplot2` (which has more decent default time and date axes).

Comment: Did you consider subclassing zoo or xts and then modifying the plot method for your new class?

Comment: It is doable.  Can you provide reproducible data?

Answer (score 1):

Answer goes to Vincent Zoonekynd.
You can use `format` argument in `plot` function to output the data in "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" format.
Please see the code below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ms = c(10485849612, 10477641600, 10561104000, 10562745600),
  value = 1:4
)

df$posix_time <- as.POSIXct(df$ms, origin = "1582-10-14", tz = "GMT")
plot(df$posix_time, df$value, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Output:
[image: output for posix_ct w/hours and minutes]